# Mix of fixed and responsive columns inside responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to create mix of fixed(-width) and non-fixed(-width) columns inside responsive column using last bootstrap 3?

Reason: i want to collapse fixed sidebar at small screens.

[image: Desirable result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that should help you:

http://bootply.com/9Efmu4rR07

Basically you use a wrapper outside the column layout, and use absolute position to position the sidebar accordingly on larger screens; collapse sidebar on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do this, Try this (bootstrap3)

```
    <div class="container-custom row">

    <div class="side-bar">Menu</div>

    <div class="content">responsive Content part
<div class="container"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>
</div>

    </div>

.Container-custom{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

.side-bar{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
}

.content{
margin-left: 250px;
min-height: 1006px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #e5e9ec;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}
```